# Using XA transaction with JDBC, MySQL, and Microsoft SQL Server

Tags: mysql, sql-server, jdbc, xa

Suppose I have MySQL server running on one machine, a Microsoft SQL Server running on a second machine, and my own custom Java database running on a third machine.

How do I use the X/Open XA standard to run a distributed transaction across all three?

Does X/Open XA specify a protocol layered over TCP or UDP? I could not find any information on this. XA appears to not specify anything about networking in which case how can it be used to run a distributed transaction across MySQL, SQL Server, and a custom Java database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is on the database to provide support for 2 phase commit transactions. In general they provide a different implementation of their ConnectionPool. If your Java application runs on an application server you must explicitly define an XA DataSource.

XA does not need to specify any low level network requirements. It's an application protocol, WikiPedia provides a nice overview: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2PC

So, if you want to implement a distributed connection, all participants must provide an XA capable interface.

Comment: Let me see if I understand what you are saying. The transaction manager will need to link to a client library for MySQL that implements the application protocol that the MySQL server expects requests to use. This could be built on TCP or UDP or anything else. It is left unspecified. And the same for the SQL Server and the custom Java database. In total 3 connection libraries will need to be linked to. The client libraries for MySQL and SQL Server are already implemented. And implementing it for the Java database is part of implementing XA support for the Java database.

Comment: Each of the 3 connections give back some way of creating some kind of XA object that the transaction manager can use when creating the distributed transaction.  
In practice is TCP used over UDP even though it adds a response trip. Do you know what the data packets typically look like? When exactly are the transaction statements to be executed sent? Are they part of the prepare message?

Comment: No, I don't know how the packets look like. I suppose it Database vendor specific, you don't have to take care. Pretty sure this is not handled on the TCP/IP layer. This is an application specific protocol, ISO/OSI layers 5-7.